# How to save a "complete" JSON response in a postgres field with PHP

Tags: php, json, postgresql

So I've read several threads where people talk about how to save a JSON respons in a DB but I cannot find a thread with my specific case.

I have a table where I would like so save the raw, complete, json respons in one field in my table. The table has other fields to.

This is the structure of the table:
`id, (int)`
`result_date, (date)`
`result_json`, (don't know if I should use json or text, tried both)

So, to me this looks like a fairly easy task, but I keep getting errors, and only some results actually get saved in the db, some give errors.

**The error I get is:**
ErrorException
`Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json DETAIL:  Token &quot;names&quot; is invalid`.

**The code is:**

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$jsonInsert = pg_escape_string($json);

$result_update_keyword_data = pg_query_params($db, "UPDATE table_json SET result_json = $1 WHERE id = $2 AND result_date = CURRENT_DATE", array($jsonInsert, $id));
```

Comment: Check whether your `json` is valid (syntax) , at jsonlint.com (others available).  If not, fix the data source for the json.

Comment: And what is the question here? If you should use `json` or `text`? Use `json` (or even better `jsonb`) if the data is always valid JSON (apparently it isn't) but `text` if the data can be something else than valid JSON but you want to store that anyway.

Comment: The question is both I guess. The source is valid json. I've tried to use both "text" and "jsonb" as the field type but still get that error.

Comment: That combination of `pg_escape_string` and `pg_query_params` doesn’t make much sense to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe well that didn't help me much. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Escaping data would be necessary, if you inserted the data into the SQL query syntax _directly_. But you are not even doing that here, with that `pg_query_params` call, you are using placeholders inside the query, and the actual data is passed _separate_ from the SQL query syntax, so there is no need for escaping in the first place; if anything, this would _falsify_ your data, if it contains any “special characters” that would be escaped by  `pg_escape_string`.

Comment: @CBroe Thx! That make sense. I'll work on that.

Comment: That solved it actually. Thx @CBro.

Answer (score 1):

As @CBro mentioned, I accidently "falsified" my data by using pg_query_params. I changed it to pg_query and it worked just fine.

```
$result_insert_keyword_data = pg_query($db,"INSERT INTO table_json(keyword_id,result_date,result_json) VALUES('".$id."', CURRENT_DATE,'".$jsonInsert."')");
```

I used JSONB as the database field type.